# Non contiguous array pointer traversing issue in pybind11?

Tags: python, c++, arrays, pybind11

Please does anyone have any idea why when I pass my 2 dim Numpy float64 (Double) array normally it prints row by row correctly, col1, col2, col3, col4 as I traverse the pointer by using pos.

**However when I pass a particular numpy array of shape 42 rows, 4 cols it instead prints, all of col1, then all of col2, all of col3 and all of col4, rather than a row at a time, please can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?**

**I welcome any and all tips as to the potential cause or a resolution :)**

I was thinking perhaps its due to memory limitations, however other arrays which are larger don't have any issues

Please note I'm using pybind11 to pass my numpy array to C++, which then traverses the ptr to print out each row at a time, which has been working nicely for "array A" & "array B" except for the new "array C" which is 42 rows by 4 columns, all arrays are float 64.

```
   void Pricing::print_array_simple(py::array_t<double>& in_results) {
    
    if (in_results.ndim() != 2) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Results should be a 2-D Numpy array");
    }

    py::buffer_info buf = in_results.request();

    double* ptr = (double*)buf.ptr;
    int array_number_rows =in_results.shape()[0]; //rows
    int array_max_size = in_results.shape()[1];//cols
    cout << "rows: " << array_number_rows << " Cols: " << array_max_size << "\n";

    size_t pos = 0;

    std::cout << "\n---- START OF ARRAY ----\n";      
        
        for (size_t i = 0; i < array_number_rows; i++) {
        //rows

            for (size_t j = 0; j < array_max_size; j++) {
                //cols
                
                std::cout << std::left <<std::setw(12) <<ptr[pos];          
                pos++;
            }
        std::cout << "|\n";
            
        }
        

}
```

Array that work correctly (72, 7) e.g. Array A or Array B:

```
    CCY  TENOR        BID        ASK        MID  LAST_BID_TIME_TODAY_REALTIME  SETTLEMENT_DATE_RT
0   1.0    1.0  1265.2000  1266.7000  1265.9500                  1.651646e+09        1.652051e+09
1   1.0    2.0  1265.3600  1266.3500  1265.8600                  1.651661e+09        1.652656e+09
2   1.0    3.0  1265.2400  1266.2800  1265.7600                  1.651662e+09        1.654729e+09
3   1.0    4.0  1264.4500  1265.5500  1265.0000                  1.651662e+09        1.657494e+09
4   1.0    5.0  1263.5600  1264.6400  1264.1000                  1.651662e+09        1.660000e+09
..  ...    ...        ...        ...        ...                           ...                 ...
67  6.0    8.0     6.7351     6.7411     6.7381                  1.651662e+09        1.683500e+09
68  6.0    9.0     6.7870     6.7970     6.7920                  1.651662e+09        1.714950e+09
69  6.0   10.0     6.8431     6.8614     6.8522                  1.651662e+09        1.746486e+09
70  6.0   11.0     6.9734     6.9883     6.9809                  1.651662e+09        1.778022e+09
71  6.0   12.0     7.1178     7.1277     7.1228                  1.651659e+09        1.809558e+09
```

C++ output:

```
---- START OF ARRAY ----
1           1           1265.2      1266.7      1265.95     1.65165e+09 1.65205e+09 |
1           2           1265.36     1266.35     1265.86     1.65166e+09 1.65266e+09 |
1           3           1265.24     1266.28     1265.76     1.65166e+09 1.65473e+09 |
1           4           1264.45     1265.55     1265        1.65166e+09 1.65749e+09 |
1           5           1263.56     1264.64     1264.1      1.65166e+09 1.66e+09    |
1           6           1259.79     1262.01     1260.9      1.65166e+09 1.66795e+09 |
1           7           1256.05     1258.09     1257.07     1.65166e+09 1.6759e+09  |
1           8           1250.87     1254.47     1252.67     1.65166e+09 1.68359e+09 |
1           9           1242.32     1244.57     1243.44     1.65166e+09 1.71521e+09 |
1           10          1233.71     1243.59     1238.65     1.65165e+09 1.74675e+09 |
1           11          1234.94     1242.71     1238.82     1.65165e+09 1.77845e+09 |
1           12          1228.37     1236.78     1232.57     1.65165e+09 1.8099e+09  |
2           1           76.4175     76.425      76.4213     1.65166e+09 1.65179e+09 |
```

This array doesn't work, 42 rows by 4 cols e.g."array C":

```
  CCY  TENOR         BID         ASK
    0   1.0    0.0   1255.9000   1256.4000
    1   1.0    1.0   1256.0000   1256.5000
    2   1.0    2.0   1255.4000   1256.0000
    3   1.0    3.0   1254.6000   1255.2000
    4   1.0    4.0   1251.4000   1252.2000
    5   1.0    5.0   1247.7000   1248.5000
    6   1.0    6.0   1244.0000   1244.9000
    7   2.0    0.0     76.2600     76.3000
    8   2.0    1.0     76.4600     76.5100
    9   2.0    2.0     76.7300     76.7900
    10  2.0    3.0     77.0100     77.0700
    11  2.0    4.0     77.8100     77.8800
    12  2.0    5.0     78.5600     78.6500
    13  2.0    6.0     79.4900     79.5700
```

output in C++:

It iterates through the CCY's, then iterates through the Tenors, then iterates through the Bids & then the Asks.

```
---- START OF ARRAY ----
1           1           1           1           |
1           1           1           2           |
2           2           2           2           |
2           2           3           3           |
3           3           3           3           |
3           4           4           4           |
4           4           4           4           |
5           5           5           5           |
5           5           5           6           |
6           6           6           6           |
6           6           0           1           |
6           0           1           2           |
3           4           5           6           |
0           1           2           3           |
4           5           6           0           |
1           2           3           4           |
5           6           0           1           |
2           3           4           5           |
3           4           5           6           |
1255.9      1256        1255.4      1254.6      |
1251.4      1247.7      1244        76.26       |
76.46       76.73       77.01       77.81       |
78.56       79.49       29.46       29.41       |
29.335      29.265      29.07       28.89       |
28.705      14442       14470       14507       |
14545       14650       14755       14860       |
52.41       52.63       52.82       52.97       |
53.38       53.72       54.02       6.6681      |
6.6861      6.7026      6.7151      6.7416      |
6.7571      6.7681      1256.4      1256.5      |
1256        1255.2      1252.2      1248.5      |
1244.9      76.3        76.51       76.79       |
77.07       77.88       78.65       79.57       |
29.485      29.44       29.375      29.305      |
29.12       28.94       28.755      14442       |
14480       14523       14565       14680       |
14785       14900       52.45       52.68       |
52.88       53.03       53.45       53.8        |
54.1        6.6711      6.6911      6.7086      |
6.7221      6.7486      6.7641      6.7761      |
```

Python

```
Python code to create array C:
lst = []
for i in range(1,7):
    for j in range(7):
        lst.append([float(i),float(j),123.1, 124.1])
lst
arr_example = np.array(lst)
arr_example
```

**Update:
then pass arr_example into the function, it seems to work when I make the array like, this, I think it is because in python in reality I am using df.values to extra the np array from the pandas dataframe which causes issues, anyone have any ideas if this is likely, understand what causes the different memory order of the numpy array?**

Comment: All we have is C++ code, and your promise that the array you're sending over has the data you expect it to have.  Thus it is going to be near impossible to give you an answer, given what you've posted.  The C++ code is not going to have a mind of its own and behave differently *if* the array contains the elements in the way you say they are being sent over.  So the conclusion *may be* on the sending side, not the receiving side.

Comment: Also, if it is non-contiguous as you claim, I don't see `ptr` being reseated for each row encountered,  Instead, `ptr` is treated as if the data is contiguous.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thank you, I shall try to upload a python generator of the underlying numpy array quickly soon. Thanks

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Please may you see my python code, update above, I think it may be related to the pandas dataframe to numpy array conversion when I call pandas.values to generate the 2D numpy array that may be causing this, however am unsure, perhaps due to needing to perform a deep copy in python first? any ideas or understanding are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a Numpy array from scratch in numpy rather than by converting from Pandas to numpy, df.values then the contiguous and correct order is maintained.

:)

e.g. the below works well:

```
Python code to create array C:
lst = []
for i in range(1,7):
    for j in range(7):
        lst.append([float(i),float(j),123.1, 124.1])
lst
arr_example = np.array(lst)
arr_example
```